# ArrayList size() return 1 when it reallly has more values

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist

In an Android app (Android Studio), I have a list that displays multiple values. It is possible to add and remove items from the list, however, it sometimes (not always) fails. Putting a breakpoint, I have seen that when obtaining the size of the ArrayList, it acts as if it only had one value when in fact it has several. Whay is happening here?

```
if(amigos.size() == 1){
    int a = 0; //Breakpoint here (enter, but in debug appear thay it has 5 values, I add also an image) [1]
}
        
for(int i = 0; i < amigos.size(); i++){ 
      
    if(amigos.get(i).getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(nombreAmigo)){

        amigos.remove(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

[Image of what I have explained before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgvEP.png)

I fill the Arraylist in an async class, in the background after get data from the server, like this:

```
try {
    //json = new JSONObject(resultado);
    json = new JSONObject(resultado.substring(resultado.indexOf("{"), resultado.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
    JSONArray jsonArray = json.optJSONArray("amigosLista");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonArrayChild = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        amigos.add(new DatosJugador(String.valueOf(jsonArrayChild
                            .optString("avatar")), String.valueOf(jsonArrayChild
                            .optString("nombre")), String.valueOf(jsonArrayChild
                            .optString("puntos"))));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    return false;
}
```

When it happens, not always, it causes the next error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: lorenzo.gaizka.tfmtapfastmultimode, PID: 4157
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:168)
    at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3526)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23005)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4508)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4526)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4499)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4526)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4499)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4526)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4499)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4526)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4499)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4526)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4499)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4526)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4499)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4526)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4499)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4526)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4499)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4526)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4499)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21822)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4526)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4499)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21822)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:534)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:542)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:625)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4652)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:4370)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3481)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2272)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8999)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1160)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:950)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:879)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1142)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8319)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
```

Comment: Could you please show how you put values into this ArrayList?

Comment: It seems like a concurrence problem, but please, in order to create a more readable and useful post, format it properly.

Comment: Changed, thank you. In the breakpoint, debug mode says that size is 5, but it enter on size == 1 clause. It's strange.

Comment: You are not checking if this async class has finished "his job" before you check the size of the ArrayList in your if clause. So, even if setting a BP inside of your if clause, you see that size is 5, you don't know if at the moment that this size was evaluated, the size was 1 or not. You should find a way to verify that the insertion of values ​​in the ArrayList has finished before you check its size.

Comment: But I can see the values in a ListView (so the process of fill the ArrayList has finished), and after a long click, I check the size. In debug mode it confirms that the value is 5.